# I cannot change GRUB to Windows MBR

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

I know this is a question that gets asked alot but none of the previous solutions have worked for me.  I reformatted my Ubuntu hard drive because I needed the space.  This was not a partition but the entire drive.  After doing so I got the expected GRUB error "unknown file system"  I then used my Windows 8 CD to go into troubleshooting mode, open command prompt and use these commands

bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot

no luck.  I then made a bootable USB and put boot-repair on it.  I tried to change the mbr to windows from there but no luck.  Here are the results http://paste.ubuntu.com/13681744/

I then tried to install windows on the drive I had partitioned but once i got to the restart computer part of the install it took me to the same GRUB error.

After all that I just wanted my computer to work so I figured I would just reinstall ubuntu on the affected drive BUT I have upgraded my computer since my original install and the Nvidia 970 I have is not compatible with the ubuntu installer, I just get a black screen.  I even went as far as putting back in my old graphics card but it doesn't display anything on boot up (which i find strange).  Plz help I'm losing my mind trying to fix this on my own.

Specs: 
Nvidia 970 gtx
AMD FX 8150
Gigabyte Ultra Durable 3

Comment: Do you have an EFI BIOS? Does it run in UEFI or in legacy/MBR mode?

Answer (score 2):

**Easier route:**

1. Boot into a Windows repair disk or Windows installer disk.
2. Once you're booted, you should see a window where you can configure keyboard and language. If not, proceed to step 3.
3. [Installer Disk Only] It should prompt you to install Windows (Install Now button). Instead of proceeding, you should see "Repair computer" or something on the lower left corner of the window.
4. Go to `Troubleshoot -> Advanced options -> Startup Repair` (Windows 10) Or just select `Startup Repair` from the menu (Windows 7)
5. Let it do its thing while you cross your fingers.

Answer (score 1):

Newer Windows installations use UEFI instead of MBR and as such simply overwriting the MBR does little to keep grub away.

The solution is to follow the following:

1. Boot into a Live Linux distro or anything so that you may read and write data to the ESP (or the EFI partition).
   The following commands are for ubuntu, convert into something similar for the platform you have booted into.
2. Find your EFI partition. Run `sudo fdisk -l` to see the partitions on all attached drives. The EFI partition has `EFI Partition` under the Type column.
3. Mount it. Suppose your EFI partition was `/dev/sda2`. Then mount it on an empty folder anywhere.

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/efipart
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/efipart
   ```
4. Now we have to find the directory Ubuntu or any other distro's name in this partition. It is mostly under `EFI/distro_name`.
5. Remove that directory and its contents by (**EXERCISE CAUTION**) `sudo rm -r distro_name`.
6. Install `efibootmgr` to fix you Firmware's boot entries.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
   sudo efibootmgr
   ```
7. The `sudo efibootmgr` command will list all UEFI boot entries. Look for the one you want to remove and note it's number (like 0001, 0002, 0003 ...) then run `sudo efibootmgr -b chosen_number -B`
8. Reboot and you now have a clean EFI partition and can proceed to installing Windows.
9. To check if this worked you should go to the boot menu options (usually pressing F9 or F12 when the system boots) and see if the entry titled Ubuntu or some other GRUB dependent OS is still present or not. If all went well, there should no linux related entries.

Comment: This is all waaaay over my head, All i wanted was to try out Linux :/ what is a UEFI and how can I boot into a linux destro if I cannot get past the "try ubuntu without installing" message because of my graphics card? And what is a linux destro....

Comment: Okay. I will walk you through it step by step... I'll edit my answer to be more beginner friendly. PS: Did you completely format the hard disk? There is no OS on it right now?

Comment: Yes, so I have to admit defeat on this one.  My cousin works on the cloud infrastructure for GoDaddy and literally does this stuff all day.  He has agreed to help me in person so with these instructions we should be able to bang it out in no time.  Thank you very much for your assistance.  Feel free to close this ticket.

Comment: If you run into any other problem, feel free to comment here again. AND PS: If this solves your issue, don't forget to come back here and mark this as the answer. (the little grey tick underneath the arrows on the left side)